# ASP.NET Core 1.0.1 not avaliable for Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

The initial ASP.NET Core 1.0 release got an update to .NET Core 1.0.1 which is avaliable on the ASP.NET downloadpage [for Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows). It seems bundled with Visual Studio (".NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2"). So I upgraded my ASP.NET Core 1.0 project to 1.0.1 on my Windows 10 development-machine.

As the application runs on Ubuntu, I also want to upgrade my testserver running Ubuntu 16.04 to the latest 1.0.1 version. But I can't find any release for linux. The downloadpage refers to the package dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003131 and I couldn't finy any package for 1.0.1 in the repo. Also in the *other downloads* section are only deb/tar packages for 1.0.1. Only the 1.1 preview, which I don't want to install cause its no final release yet.

Comment: donet-dev is the SDK, not Asp.Net core framework 1.0.1 is available for windows, linux and OSX. It'll be downloaded by the instaler

Answer (score 4):

If you follow(ed) the instructions on https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu you should be able to update via `apt`.
Be aware that there are 2 version numbers. one is the runtime, which is `1.0.1`. The other is the SDK that provides commands like `dotnet restore`, `dotnet build` and so on.

The SDK also includes the runtime. The SDK version `1.0.0-preview2-003131` includes the runtime `1.0.1`. The previously released version that had the `1.0.0` runtime had a lower number after the `preview2-` part..

Comment: "The previously released version that had the 1.0.0 runtime had a lower number after the preview2- part" I believe it was 003121.